# How to run same Maven profile with different parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

Work currently uses ANT and need to migrate to MAVEN. As stated above , I need to run same profile but with different parameters each time.

Present Ant Code Example :

```
<target name = SomeTarget>
<var name = "PROP" value="123">
<antcall target = "OutTarget1">
<var name = "PROP" value="145">
<antcall target = "OutTarget1">
</target>

<target name ="OutTarget1">
<!-- some java code -->
<!-- run .SQL files -->
<!-- some java code on that again -->
<\target>
```

Doesn't seem like even with maven antrun plugin antcall is supported.

Work requires I create all targets as profiles in pom.xml. Now I can simply repeat the "OutTarget1" code in execution part of a profile for each time there is a new property. But that makes it quite hard to debug. And there's a ton of a t targets calling other targets.

If it was just one antcall , I add the parameter in launch configuration. I have no idea how to achieve this when it's same parameter but different values each time.

P.S. Added what OutTarget does. It's basically the same process  but with diff values each time.

Comment: I would not add targets as profiles in Maven. This is not how profiles are meant to be used. First you need to figure out what these Ant targets are for, so if they test, compile or what else. Then you can find an appropriate phase for them in the Maven lifecycle. Furthermore, from experience I can say that most Ant targets will be replaceable by Maven plugins.

Comment: J Fabian Meier - most are compile and prepare-package phases where the OutTargets run .SQL files I believe. It's a multi module project and recursively run them all at once. That's where the property thing comes up

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to do is a good approach, but if it's urgent...have you considered using different settings-[X].xml, with the same profile defined differently and launch maven pointing to them?

Comment: That'd be cumbersome and I am better off giving a prop value in launch file itself. Guess have to break it down to more individual parts with diff. Prop values.